# How to stop multiple processes from creating multiple instances of another process?

Tags: python, concurrency, race-condition

I have 2 processes: Start and Status. There can be multiple Start processes executed on the same time and there should only be 1 instance of Status process.

On startup of the Start process, it will attempt to start Status. At the moment, I try to stop multiple Statuses from starting by getting the Status process to check if Status's server port has been binded to determine if there is another Status that exists and if so it will shutdown gracefully.

However this has a race condition where the time it checks for the binded port, there might be another Status that had done that check and is in the process of binding that port, hence 2 Statuses will be created.

Is there a process level solution to this? I have considered having another process monitoring the number of Statuses in the System but is there another approach?

Edit: This is done in Python 2.6

Edit2: Both Start and Status are excuted from the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to coordinate running of processes.  It's actually quite good.  You basically configure your processes, the max number that can run, etc and it will handle the rest.  You need to figure out all the little configuration items, though. You might also want to break out that status process to be its own if you have it running as a thread in another process.  You'll have better success that way.

You can make this less of an issue probably if you changed how you handled this. Instead of a check then execute, just execute and handle the error.

```
try: 
    open_port_listener()
except socket.error as e:
    do_nothing()
```

Or maybe put in a little more granular check on the type of socket error.  I am assuming you are using `socket` and are getting a socket.error (probably Address already in use or something?).

If you were running this using the `multiprocessing` module (which I know you aren't since you clarified, but I'll leave this in just in case it is useful for anyone else), you could use a lock to ensure the status process check occurs on one process or another. The `multiprocessing` module supports this. Read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes).

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def startStatusProcess(l):
    l.acquire()    
    if not do_check():
        Process(target=runStatusProcess, args=()).start()
    l.release() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    startStatusProcess(lock)
```

Comment: I tried reading the docs but it doesn't have details on how locking works across multiple processes. Since there can be multiple Start processes, the locking will only ensure there is only 1 Status for that Start process? Or is it across all Start processes?

Comment: Basically, `acquire()` will issue a lock.  If a second process attempts `acquire()` after the first, it will block at that statement until the first process issues `release()`.  Doing this prevents the process check and execution from running in parallel to another process' check and execution.  Just keep in mind, it must be the same `Lock()` object.

Comment: Also, I was assuming you were using the `multiprocessing` module.  If this is not the case, and you are running multiple executions from the shell, then I would go with something like [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/).

Comment: Both Start and Status is executed from the shell, sorry for the lack of that detail from the OP. I will update it.

Comment: Yep, I am trying to bind then catching for a socket error to see if it is already in use. The problem is that I have to use a another mandated 3rd party tcp/ip layer so if it binded successfully, I have to unbind and then make calls to that 3rd party layer. In that stage a race condition can happen.

Comment: What if the process gets killed? kill -9

Answer (score 0):

There are likely pythonic ways, but myself I would use a process supervisor like daemontools, systemd, runit etc - to start and supervise the status process to ensure there is one and only one.